Policy proposal: Concerns about tone in questions that mention specific individuals
Today, I voted to close this question about a specific Oxford PhD student and her appeals and potential law suit. I have previously voted to close other questions that ask about specific individuals, although I haven't kept a list.
Edit: I originally proposed a straightforward ban on these kinds of posts. I have edited this to reflect my change in thought based on feedback.
Questions that ask about specific individuals often have an aggressive-to-toxic tone1, even if they have a hint of an on-topic and generalizable question.
I think that we should provide strict guidelines about mentioning specific individuals in academia. It has long been our policy (2014) to not ask questions about specific universities, "questions about specific programs, courses, curricula, projects, and research topics are considered off-topic here," see also this 2015 Meta Q&A.
We currently have a policy against "making allegations against named individuals or organizations." Perhaps the first question could be considered an allegation against Oxford (although 1. not first alleged here and 2. perhaps not "severe").
I think we should go farther. In the end, most questions about a specific individual come down to the policies at their institution (or laws in their country, etc., etc.). I'll quote from Allure's answer to the first question:

I don't have an internal view of Oxford .... So it's possible her complaint has merit; I simply don't know, and probably nobody except those with direct knowledge of the process do.

I propose we institute strict guidelines about how to format questions about specific people (or, spurred by popular new articles). Having a guideline will let community members feel empowered to overhaul questions, where usually we prefer to leave OP's voice as much as possible.

Individuals have sometimes been mentioned by name, as examples of personal-name, e.g. Simon Baron-Cohen and António Franco de Oliveira Falcão, which I suggest is fine.

Footnote 1: Toxic questions include the Oxford question, This one about the former president of Harvard, and this question about the 2024 Nobel Prize in Physics, which was CV'ed as off topic for different reasons.

Other relevant questions (collecting suggestions from comments, etc.):

This well-received question about Taiwan's ex-president, which shows how to ask a question inspired by an individual without attacking them.

This question about US honors, inspired by an individual, that IMO is also a decent example of how to ask these kinds of questions.

This one about President Obama publishing a paper in JAMA.



I agree this question should be closed. I'm not sure about the overall policy, though, I think existing policies already cover it for the most part and we tend to be more open to questions about things that are in the public academic news, even if they involve specific institutions, individuals, etc.

My gut reaction is similar to Bryan's. I was one of the close voters on both questions you linked in the first paragraph and largely agree with your sentiment. Questions that are effectively asking us to become comment threads on individual cases, no matter how famous, are usually opinion-based or too focused on individual factors. I guess the question is: Are we seeing this type of question with a frequency that merits an explicit policy rather than just having things closed as they come up?

@user176372 Having a policy is free. I don't think that we are bogged down by too many policies at the moment. I would honestly rather see mods be enable to mod-hammer these questions closed immediately rather than let them stay open until five CVs are accumulated.

@BryanKrause Between the two policies I linked, I think there's still room to clarify. I would be fine with a question about a specific university if they're in the news. I'm less comfortable with questions about specific individuals.

The question about Obama's JAMA paper is perhaps also relevant. While it did attract close votes at the time, I think it shows that some questions about individuals can be meaningfully answered here. Of course, it very much helps if the question is phrased productively from the start.

@Anyon I think that an exception for people who are public figures outside of academia would be fine. My point here is about not aiming the site at members of the academic community, which POTUS and the president of Taiwan (from below) have their own notability

I would vote "no" on a policy as you propose. Once a case makes the news, or an individual becomes a public figure, then it is generally appropriate for us to comment. I don't see any need per se to close these questions.
On the other hand, I would support a general "best practice" that public figures or famous cases should be presented as examples of a deeper question when possible (rather than just asking for comment on a particular case).
In brief, my rationale is that these questions are often interesting and we should avoid the knee-jerk reaction of voting to close, instead editing as needed. For example, "Did the president of Taiwan receive a half-PhD?" would trigger summary closure under your proposed policy, and even without your proposal would probably be close-voted to death. But the isomorphic formulation of "Is there such a thing as a half-PhD? I heard the president of Taiwan received one" turned out to be a an interesting and well-received question. Making edits to turn the former question into the latter is a best practice. (I'm not suggesting "forced edits," but you can cite this page as justification for why the edit is appropriate).

Let's look at the questions you cite:
The Shakespeare student. There are a few issues here.

First, it is horribly written with this giant copy-paste. For sure it should be closed until it is rewritten.
If it is rewritten but otherwise unchanged, I think it's borderline. The case is public, and the student is trying to get publicity, so I have no concerns along those lines. Rather, my concern is that we have only the student's side of the story, so it will be a lot of speculation. Still, we often have only half the story and have to speculate.
If it is rewritten to something more objective like: "Does Shakespeare have scope for a PhD thesis?" or "What is the required scope for a PhD in Literature?" and lists this case as an example, then this could be an interesting question.

The 2024 Nobel Prize in Physics.

We have already ruled that Nobel Prizes are on topic here.
This question has biased wording, which probably soured people on it.
Other than that, I would argue this question is OK and shouldn't have been closed. That said, I'm not going to spend energy trying to correct this injustice because the question is pretty low-quality: the official reasoning is already available online and all we can do is copy-and-paste that explanation, perhaps with our own speculation added.

Harvard's ex-President.

This case has already gotten ample publicity.
This is an unusual case where we probably do have enough information to make a judgment, since the thesis is public and the purported plagiarism probably is as well. Or we could cite the other experts who have already looked at this case in detail.
I think the only reason this was closed was because it is too broad, asking both (1) is omitting a citation really plagiarism, and (2) did she deserve her severe punishment. The first of these could be asked in the abstract, and has been several times in several different forms. The latter is probably an interesting question that could be asked more generally, with the newsworthy case listed as an example.


As a somewhat tangential related comment (mostly consulting the Harvard ex-president question): My threshold for closing questions for being opinion-based lowers substantially for borderline questions which are clearly related to a topic that has been in the news very recently. These have a tendency to hit HNQ and then attract more answers than our community seems able to police with upvotes/downvotes effectively. Regarding editing: Often the original poster is unenthusiastic for making their own edits, and enforced edits are controversial.

Thanks for the reply. Your third bullet point tho for the Shakespeare Q is essentially “edit out the reference to a specific individual or make it an example,” which I think is consistent with what I’m proposing. I left the Nobel prize in as related, not necessarily a core example. I’m not sure it should be open but let’s set that aside (it mentions no one by name).

What about a guidance that posts should ask a general question and mention specific individuals only as an example, if at all necessary? It’s the toxic tone in all these Qs that I would like to see addressed. To me the Taiwan president Q (I wasn't familiar with it) is an excellent example of how these questions should work.

Yes, I can agree with that. Updated the answer.
